# Adjust card width in bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In the following, how do I set all cards to have same widths? I currently see some cards exceeding the specified width because of the the table it is holding. I am viewing it on a laptop.

```
<main role="main" class="container">
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-body">

          <div class="row gutters-sm">
            <div class="col-md-15">
              <div class="card  mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">
                <!-- stuff here--> 
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row gutters-sm">
            <div class="col-md-15">
              <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">                  
                <!-- stuff here-->                   
                </div> <!--end of card-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row gutters-sm">
            <div class="col-md-15">
              <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="card-body">
               <table class="table mb-0 table-hover">
                 <thead class="bg-primary">
                   <tr>
                     <th scope="col">SSSSSS</th>
                     <th scope="col">DDDDDD</th>
                     <th scope="col">FFFFFF</th>
                     <th scope="col">TTTTTT</th>
                     <th scope="col">GGGGGGGGG</th>
                     
                     <th scope="col">AAAAAA</th>
                     
                   </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                  
                   <tr>
                   <td class="mb-0"><div class="col-md-1 text-secondary">String 1 </div></td>
                   <td class="mb-0"><div class="col-md-1 text-secondary">String 2 </div></td>
                   <td class="mb-0"><div class="col-md-1 text-secondary">String 3</div></td>
                   <td class="mb-0"><div class="col-md-1 text-secondary">String 4</div></td>
                   <td class="mb-0"><div class="col-md-1 text-secondary">TTTT    </div></td>
                   
                   <td class="mb-0">
                                   <div class="col-sm-12">
                                   <a class="btn btn-secondary " name="education" href="/edit/2">Edit</a>
                                   <a class="btn btn-danger    " name="education" href="/delete/2">Delete</a>
                                   </div>
                   </td>
                   
                   </tr>
                 </tbody>
               </table>
                <!-- stuff here-->                                     
                </div> <!--end of card body-->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

  </div>
</div>
</main>
```

Comment: Please [add your content inside the `card-body`  inside this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cz81tfL6/) I made to fix your layout. If you don't want three columns at the medium breakpoint remove `.row-cols-md-3` from `.row`. Know that Bootstrap uses a 12 column flex grid, so `col-md-15` doesn't do anything. Please add your 'tables' otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Can I not normalize width of all cards in a container to adjust their width to match the width of the widest card?

Comment: Please add the code. Your cards in the example above are empty.

Comment: Added. Also, how do I center all the cards?

Comment: The width of your cards are determined by the width of the parent columns. Since you have one column per row, each column will take the full width of the row. So I cannot answer your question since all cards already share the same width. There's also nothing to center with your current layout. [More info in the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/card/#card-layout). Perhaps add a pic of your desired layout so we can see what you are trying to achieve. [Here's a responsive table inside a card](https://jsfiddle.net/pruavfcg/).